# Serverless public access

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using Serverless framework to create a Lambda on AWS.

I've added this simple code to test Internet connectivity within my lambda

```
try:
    # see if we can resolve the host name -- tells us if there is
    # a DNS listening
    host = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
    # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
    # reachable
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    s.close()
    logging.info('Internet connectivity is present')
except Exception as e:
    logging.info('Internet connectivity is not present: {}'.format(e))
```

This code always fails to connect to Internet saying `timed out`. I'm launching my lambda in my own VPC (I'm re-using RDS VPC to be specific)

I've created my own VPC and it has few subnets each has connectivity to Internet Gateway

[image: Subnet having Internet connectivity]

This is what my security group configuration looks like

[image: Security Group allows outbound traffic]

As given [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/), if the subnet has igw route then it should have Internet access. Which I've verified by launching an EC2 instance and trying to ping from there and I was successful in doing so.

What am I missing here? How do I enable Internet access from my Lambda code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have understood it correct but Lambda in VPC works slightly different. To get Internet Access from Lambda in VPC, you need to have a NAT gateway , NAT instance etc , you can't work with IGW with Lambda because ENI used for Lambda doesn't get assigned a public IP address hence IGW route doesn't work.

Here is the document:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

You can attached a NAT gateway to the Subnet Routing table and it would work. (NAT gateway should be launched in Subnet with routing table with IGW)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I followed the process mentioned in the document. But I'm getting same error.

Comment: After following steps, I had forgotten to associate public route table with public network. For private network, I had done.Thanks for the answer James.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda will not get a public ip, so you need a NAT gateway in a public subnet. The routing table to internet gateway is not a valid option. When you turn on a VPC in your Lambda function, the info message will appear.

> When you enable a VPC, your Lambda function loses default internet access. If you require external internet access for your function, make sure that your security group allows outbound connections and that your VPC has a NAT gateway.

Comment: I tried creating NAT gateway but I'm still getting the same error.